# Perl SMTP auth fails when password is passed via variable

Tags: perl, environment-variables, smtp, gmail

I have several hundred Perl scripts that send email via gmail SMTP. All are, and have been working fine for a couple of years with the gmail password hard-coded.

To simplify password changes (and for security), I want to move the password to an env var, and pull that into the perl scripts. I am using the code below.

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new('smtp.gmail.com', Port => 465);
my $passwd = $ENV{'PASSWD'}; # I added this line
$smtp->auth('email@gmail.com', $passwd); # I replaced 'theHardCodedPassWord' with $passwd
```

The same method works in a non-smtp scenario -- I pull info from an env var and use it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sanity-check (with debug statements or by retracing your steps) that `$ENV{'PASSWD'}` is really there, and really contains what you think it does. For instance  there could be extra characters sneaking into it, like whitespace, quotes, escape characters, etc.

Comment: Might be a encoding issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437877/how-can-i-properly-use-environment-variables-encoded-as-windows-1251-in-perl

Comment: Beyond the other excellent suggestions, I’d put $passwd in double quotes in the last line.

Comment: @jimtut: Why? That would make no difference at all.

Comment: I’ve seen that help with strings that have unexpected characters in them, like spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious debugging approaches:

- Print the values of `$ENV{PASSWD}` and `$passwd` before the call to `auth()`.
- Turn on debug output in the Net::SMTP::SSL object (add `Debug => 1` to the call to `new()`).

A few other points:

- The documentation for [Net::SMTP::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP::SSL) is pretty clear that the module is deprecated and should no longer be used. It says that Net::SMTP now has built-in support for SSL connections.
- Net::SMTP seems to be a rather low-level approach to this problem. Have you considered [Email::Send::Gmail](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Send::Gmail)? I've even had success sending email through GMail with [Email::Sender::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Simple).
- I know that GMail recently hardened their security around using their SMTP servers from external apps. There's more information about this change [on the Google support site](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255).

Comment: Thanks. I know you are right; the code should be updated. I inherited ~20 year old code, and lots of it. I will explore your suggestions.